# Why an activity doesn't start?

Tags: java, android

I call an aidl method that calls me back after some logic, in this callback method I try to start an Activity, but the activity doesn't start and there are no exceptions. Interesting fact, it works on Android 9, but on 10 and 6 doesn't.

Manifest

```
<activity
            android:name=".views.ReceiptsActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.bifit.cashdesk.mobile.views.ReceiptsActivity" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

StartActivity() Method

```
    private void showActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, context.getClass());
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Aidl callback method

```
aidlService.cancel(new IOperationResponse.Stub() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String resultCode, String responseData, String rrn, String billJson) {
                    showActivity();
                }
            }, "com.bifit.cashdesk.mobile.views.ReceiptsActivity", rrn);
```

I have tried to resolve this by user-permissions, but it haven't led to success

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure that `context` is  always an `activity` in `showActivity()`?

Comment: @Themelis yes, it only is ReceiptActivity

Comment: I also have the same issue. Fine working in lower than 9 and not starting in android 9 and upper . Ithink the issue is related to the inner methods of aidl . Not starting onResult . Maybe you are not reaching to calling of showActivity() method.

Comment: @maniaq I have caught calling by debugger

Comment: I think this is not an your issue. This is issue of implementation of adil (Contact with your supporter of your app store)

Comment: @maniaq We resolve it with the aidl developer, he closes his app at callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was on the side of aidl app, this app didn't close when used callback. We resolved it by closing aidl app on callback on it's side